# SocialAuth java library not working as expected (using NetBeans)

Tags: java, facebook, servlets, netbeans, socialauth

I'm trying to run the socialauth spring sample (http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/SpringSample) but when I'm trying to connect with facebook the socialAuthTemplate.getSocialAuthManager() call from SuccessController.java returns null. I can't do any debugging to find out what I do wrong because it's a function from sociaauth.jar and I don't have access to its code. Has anyone had this problem before? What should I do? My only guess is that I didn't configured the project right (I didn't included some library or smth). I'm working with netbeans.

this is the code:

```
@Controller
public class SuccessController {

    @Autowired
    private SocialAuthTemplate socialAuthTemplate;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authSuccess")
    public ModelAndView getRedirectURL(final HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws Exception {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            List<Contact> contactsList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            SocialAuthManager manager = socialAuthTemplate.getSocialAuthManager();     //returns null
            AuthProvider provider = manager.getCurrentAuthProvider();
            contactsList = provider.getContactList();
            if (contactsList != null && contactsList.size() > 0) {
                    for (Contact p : contactsList) {
                            if (!StringUtils.hasLength(p.getFirstName())
                                            && !StringUtils.hasLength(p.getLastName())) {
                                    p.setFirstName(p.getDisplayName());
                            }
                    }
            }
            mv.addObject("profile", provider.getUserProfile());
            mv.addObject("contacts", contactsList);
            mv.setViewName("/jsp/authSuccess.jsp");

            return mv;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you verifythe scope of socialAuthTemplate class in your spring config file. It should have session scope.

```
 <bean id="socialAuthTemplate" class="org.brickred.socialauth.spring.bean.SocialAuthTemplate" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
```

If you require code base of socialauth, you can download the socialauth-java-sdk-2.3.zip file from following location. It contains all the source code as well as examples.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/downloads/list

Comment: I have exactly the same problem but with google+, `socialAuthTemplate.getSocialAuthManager()` returns null. I have had set the code you posted in src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\socialauthdemo-servlet.xml (its a demo project of socialauth), but it still doesnt work, whout should I try?